# Johnson's algorithm - h function

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

Johnson's algorithm uses the Bellman-Ford algorithm as a subroutine for reweighting its input graph to eliminate negative weights on its edges (assuming no negative cycles). In the standard implementation, after adding an extra node connected to all of the others with 0 weight edges, we define the new weight to be:

**w'(u,v) = w(u,v) + h(u) - h(v)**

This new weight has to satisfy two requirements:

- shortest path invariance (the shortest paths are the same in the reweighted graph)
- non-negative edge weighting (all edges must have non-negative weight)

In its standard implementation, the function h is thus defined as being the shortest path weight (the distance) from the added node to the target node:

**h(v) = d(s,v)**

So what I'm wondering is: is there a point in defining **h** otherwise? One of the aspects I'm thinking about is that running the Bellman-Ford is required for this. This is mainly out of curiosity, so even small details are important to me if there are alternatives to the "canonical" definition of **h**.

Comment: To make sure I'm getting your question correctly - you've listed two requirements for the new weights w'. Is the question "is h only used in order to find this new function w'?" Or are you asking why that choice of h is made? Or are you asking whether there's an intuition for defining w' from h? Or something else?

Comment: I'm asking if there are other choices of h which may have their perks compared to the "canonical" choice of h in the standard implementation. So finding out the advantages/intuition to h is helpful of course!

Answer (score 2):

There are two angles of attack here.

The first is changing the definition of w'. The current definition does more than preserve shortest paths; it preserves the differences between the lengths of paths connecting the same endpoints. I don't have any concrete ideas for exploiting the gap here. Unfortunately any reweighting that satisfies the stronger property has an associated h function.

The second is changing the definition of h. This angle is unpromising since when we rewrite the nonnegative condition, it looks like

```
h(w) <= h(v) + d(v, w) for all vw in E,
```

which is the same constraint as for shortest paths (the shortest paths linear program has the additional constraint that the root is at distance zero, and it seeks to maximize the sum of the distance labels). I won't say you have to do Bellman--Ford, but whatever you use to compute h has to in some sense be a shortest path algorithm that can cope with negative weights.

Comment: Hmm these are good points, thanks, I'll look into both these angles. Using something other than Bellman-Ford sounds interesting actually, so I'll look for other algorithms which can cope with negative weights. Also, very interesting point with the fact that current definition is stronger than required, that also seems like a potentially fruitful avenue of research. Thanks!